# Kubuntu 11.04 dpkg interrupted

Tags: 11.04, kubuntu, dpkg

I ran 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' in a terminal.  I was shown a DOS Menu Looking blue panel with some choices relating to keymap selections.  I am not able to enter any data.  How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

With the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key you should to be able to pick the correct selections.